# Django Form won't submit error says Select a Valid Choice ____ is not one of the available choices

Tags: django, django-forms

I built a form in django and I'm having trouble debugging my Tours Choices.  It is a ChoiceField and I use the CheckboxMultipleSelect Widget.  I don't know what I'm doing wrong to get the error in the screenshot below.  Any thoughts? Do I need to facilitate more information?  I'm a django newbie.

[Picture of the Form Error](http://www.friesen.bz/form.png)

Comment: Can we see the source code for the form, choices and model (if it's a model form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `form.ChoiceField` lets you input exactly one choice for a form (out of a selection of several choices).  If you saved it to a database in a model there would be one value stored in the database.  Your `CheckboxMultipleSelect` widget is for a `form.MultipleChoiceField` where you can input multiple values.  So change your `ChoiceField` to a `MultipleChoiceField` in your form and you should be fine.  If you save this data to a model, that model would have to be an appropriate field, like a ManyToManyField if they are Foreign Keys.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize there was a relationship between those models.  Now I got it...Multiple selects for Multiple choices! :)